# Ford Ka 2016 - 1.2 Zetec Hatchback, Car drives slow then engine cuts out + engine problem light

Tags: stall

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.

After driving for 5-60mins with no issues I come to a stop at traffic lights or roundabouts etc. then there's:
1. A loud beeping noise.
2. The dashboard engine warning light  comes on
3. Shows error "hill holder system unavailable"
4. And "auto start/stop system unavailable"

When I accelerate and release the clutch as per usual the car gets stuck at 2mph then pressing harder on the accelerator causes the car to stall.

I need to turn the engine on/off several times for the warnings to disappear and to accelerate normally again.

This can happen several time a day for several days in a row or once every few weeks.

Ford ran a diagnostics test and didn't find anything. The clutch has been checked as well, there's no slippage.

Any ideas what could cause this?